# How do I exclude a function from a namespace (the built in one) for a module in Python?

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I have this module:

```
import os
```

...

```
def map():
#And some stuff here...
```

and I want to use `module_name.map()` , but there is a `map` function built into Python...
Is there any way to exclude the function from the namespace of the module and still have it in main.py?

Comment: It's not the best idea to shadow an existing name. Does the function _have_ to be named `map()`?

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi The function is "cause" and the subfunction if it called that is "map": "cause.map()". But it still would not let me make it!